# Jenkins remote ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: windows, git, azure, jenkins, github

I don't know what that means, could someone explain what the problem is, and what the solution would be.

I've been stuck here a couple of days. 
I want to run the tests on a virtual machine on Azure.
I have updated all the Jenkins plugins.
I use Putty for the ssh tunnel

This is the console output I get when I want to run the build:

```
Started by user admin
Building remotely on testadminjenkinsazure277db0 (ubuntu) in workspace /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/DemoProject5
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/jankojanko123/my-app.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/DemoProject5 # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/DemoProject5
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:787)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:579)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to testadminjenkinsazure277db0
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init /home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/DemoProject5
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2023)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1984)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1980)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1612)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:785)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" (in directory "/home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/DemoProject5"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:936)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2012)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 20 more
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be that you're building your Jenkins job on remote Ubuntu agent (in `/home/Jenkinsadmin/workspace/DemoProject5` workspace), but path to Git you have defined as a Windows folder (`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`). So, you need to install Git on Ubuntu and set correct path to it (linux-style).

Answer (score 0):

the error says: `Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"`. this means you dont have git installed (or at least, not in this path). You need to install it.

Comment: I've installed git and I've set the path (C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe). it still doesn't work properly

Comment: how many agents you have? maybe you configured the wrong one?

Comment: I have one agent

Answer (score 0):

In the Global  Tool Configuration provide the complete path including the git.exe.....  In my case it is C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe    I got the same error when leaving the program name : C:\Program Files\Git\bin\